# Different filters for rows and columns in MDX

Tags: sql, database, mdx

I have the following MDX query

```
SELECT 
{[Year].[2020],[Year].[2019],[Year].[2020]} on 0,

{[Sales].[GER],[Position].[EU],[Position].[US],[Position].[BL]} on 1  

FROM  
[DB]    

WHERE ([Period].[FULL],[Content].[ALL],[CUR].[EUR])
```

Returning this table:

```
          YEAR   2020 (€) 2019 (€) 2020 (€) 
Position
GER                 
EU
US
BL
```

However, for each row and column I want to apply a fiter. For columns, I want the currency to change and for rows I want the Period to change.

My table should look therefore like this:

```
          YEAR   2020 ($) 2019 (€) 2020 (€) 
Position
GER (YE)                
EU (YB)
US (YE)
BL (YB)
```

I tried using subselect and filter but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The rows and columns axis are defined by sets. A set has tuples. A tuple has members. So we created a columns axis with a set of 3 tuples. Each tuple specifies two members: the year and the currency. That’s how to apply a different filter to each column.

```
SELECT 
{
([Year].[2020] ,[CUR].[USD]),
([Year].[2019] ,[CUR].[EUR]),
([Year].[2020] ,[CUR].[EUR])
} on 0,

{[Sales].[GER],[Position].[EU],[Position].[US],[Position].[BL]} on 1  

FROM  
[DB]    

WHERE ([Period].[FULL],[Content].[ALL])
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.